# (Delphi Ttreeview) how to drag/drop node to below (or above) selected node

Tags: delphi, treeview

In TtreeView1.DragDrop am using statements such as

```
 targetnode := TreeView1.GetNodeAt(x,y);
 ...
 TreeView1.Selected.MoveTo(targetnode , naInsert ) ;
```

to move a node with the mouse and insert it in front of ie above, an existing node on the same level.

Id like to change the behaviour so that if I am dragging downwards the node gets moved to below the target but if I am dragging upwards it gets moved to above the target (otherwise I can drag to a new bottom position but not a new top or vice versa).
The sort of structure I am trying is

```
targetnode := TreeView1.GetNodeAt(x,y);
...
if DraggedItem.Index > targetnode.Index then //we are dragging upwards, insert before
    TreeViewStructure.Selected.MoveTo(targetnode , naInsert ) 
else                                        //we are dragging downwards, insert after
    TreeViewStructure.Selected.MoveTo(targetnode , ???) ;
```

but I cannot find a TNodeAttachMode constant that inserts a sibling *after* the target node.
The constants for TNodeAttachMode given here http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TNodeAttachMode.html are ...

```
naAdd: The new or relocated node becomes the last sibling of the other node.
naAddFirst: The new or relocated node becomes the first sibling of the other node.  
naInsert:The new or relocated node becomes the sibling immediately before the other node.  
naAddChild:The new or relocated node becomes the last child of the other node.  
naAddChildFirst:The new or relocated node becomes the first child of the other node.
```

but none of those refer to a new last sibling.

Can I do what I want? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to insert after a node, only insert before. So you have to find the node after the drop target, and insert before it.

To add after the last node, find the last node and pass `naAdd` to `MoveTo`.

Comment: But there is no node after the last one! So if I have A, B, C, D, E and I want to reorder it to become B, C, D, E, A are you saying I cannot drag 'A' down to its new place? Are my only options to separately drag every other node (B, C, D, E) up to before the 'A' or first drag 'A' down to between 'D' and 'E' and then in a separate operation, drag 'E' up to between 'D' and 'A'?  - I can see that confusing many users.

Comment: (I have a small program called 'HelpNDoc' that shows documentation chapter headings in a tree form and that allows dragging a heading right to the bottom or right to the top so it should be possible.)

Comment: For the last node use `naAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David for his suggestions. Using them I finally wrote the following code to achieve what I need. Posted here in case it's of use to anyone else. (This is the relevant bit of code inside OnDragDrop)

```
 if ( Assigned(targetnode))  //we are over a target node
    and (DraggedNode.Level = targetnode.Level  then  //we are dragging within the same sub level
         begin
         if targetnode.Index = targetnode.Parent.Count -1  then   //target is the last node so do an naAdd to drop node at the end
              TreeViewStructure.Selected.MoveTo(targetnode , naAdd )
         else
              TreeViewStructure.Selected.MoveTo(targetnode , naInsert )   //drop before target using naInsert
         end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Dst <> nil)and(Src <> Dst) then
begin
 if Dst.getNextSibling <> nil then                                         
 begin
   varNode := Dst.GetNextChild(Dst);                                       
   Src.MoveTo(varNode, naInsert);                                          
 end
 else                                                                      
 begin
   varNode := Dst.Parent;                                                    
   Src.MoveTo(varNode, naAddChild);                                          
 end;
end;
```